# FFT and FFTShift of matlab in FFTW library c++

Tags: c++, matlab, fftw

what is the exact equivalent of this MATLAB line code in C++ and using FFTW?

```
fftshift(fft(x,4096)));
```

note: X is an array of 4096 double data.

now I use these lines of code in c++ and FFTW to compute fft

```
int n = 4096
fftw_complex *x;
fftw_complex *y;
x = (fftw_complex *)fftw_malloc(sizeof(fftw_complex) * n);
y = (fftw_complex *)fftw_malloc(sizeof(fftw_complex) * n);

for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
{
       x[i][REAL] = MyDoubleData[i];
       x[i][IMAG] = 0;
}

fftw_plan plan = fftw_plan_dft_1d(n, x, y, FFTW_FORWARD, FFTW_ESTIMATE);

fftw_execute(plan);
fftw_destroy_plan(plan);
fftw_cleanup();
```

It is just equivalent of FFT function in MATLAB.
Is there any equivalent function for FftShift in FFTW library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The FFTW function calls you've provided would be the equivalent of `fft(x,4096)`. <strike>If x is real, matlab knows to give you the conjugate symmetric FFT (I think).  If you want to do this with FFTW, you need to use the [`r2c` and `c2r` functions](http://www.fftw.org/doc/One_002dDimensional-DFTs-of-Real-Data.html) (real-to-complex/complex-to-real).</strike>

You have to do the shift yourself. You can do direct substitution (poor performance, but should be intuitive)

```
for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
{
    fftw_complex tmp;
    int src = i;
    int dst = (i + n/2 - 1) % n;

    tmp=y[src];
    y[src]=x[dst];
    y[dst]=tmp;
}
```

Alternatively use a couple memcpy's (and/or memmove's) or [modify your input data](http://www.fftw.org/faq/section3.html#centerorigin)

Comment: They are NOT equivalent to fftshift( fft( x ) ), they are equivalent to  fft( x )

Comment: The crossed out comment about real input is valid. It doesn't related to the `fftshift` part, but it's still useful. The code shown here for `fftshift` only works for even-sized arrays. For odd-sized arrays it won't shift the 0-frequency to the leftmost bin. See here for a few different correct implementations: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5915125/fftshift-ifftshift-c-c-source-code

Answer (score 1):

The output of the fftw is stored  base on following format of frequencies sequence:

```
[0....N-1]
```

Where N is number of frequencies and is oven.
And fftshift change it to:

```
[-(N-1)/2,..., 0..., (N-1)/2]
```

but you should note that fftw output has equivalent as:

`[0,.., N-1]` is same as `[0,...,(N-1)/2,-(N-1)/2,...,-1]`

This means that in DFT, frequency `-i` is same as `N-i`.