# scipy fftshift and fftw fftshift gives different values (shifted matrix are not the same)

Tags: python, c++, scipy, fft, xtensor

I have a C++ code which performs `fftshift` for a given `meshgrid`.

```cpp
    const std::size_t size = 5;
    auto ar = xt::meshgrid(xt::arange<double>(0, size), xt::arange<double>(0, size));
    int translate = (size + 1) / 2;
    
    xt::xarray<double> x = std::get<0>(ar) - translate;
    xt::xarray<double> y = std::get<1>(ar) - translate;
    xt::xarray<double> xy_ = xt::stack(xt::xtuple(x, y));
    auto p = xt::fftw::fftshift(xy_);
    std::cout << p << std::endl;
```

Which gives the following shifted matrix:

```
{{{-3., -2., -1.,  0.,  1.},
  {-3., -2., -1.,  0.,  1.},
  {-3., -2., -1.,  0.,  1.},
  {-3., -2., -1.,  0.,  1.},
  {-3., -2., -1.,  0.,  1.}},
 {{-1., -1., -1., -1., -1.},
  { 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.},
  { 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.},
  {-3., -3., -3., -3., -3.},
  {-2., -2., -2., -2., -2.}}}
```

whereas for python the same `fftshift` ()results in:

```py
np.mgrid[:size, :size] - int( (size + 1)/2 )
fftshifted_mat = scipy.fftpack.fftshift(mat)
print(fftshifted_mat)
```

```
[[[ 0  1 -3 -2 -1]
  [ 0  1 -3 -2 -1]
  [ 0  1 -3 -2 -1]
  [ 0  1 -3 -2 -1]
  [ 0  1 -3 -2 -1]]

 [[ 0  0  0  0  0]
  [ 1  1  1  1  1]
  [-3 -3 -3 -3 -3]
  [-2 -2 -2 -2 -2]
  [-1 -1 -1 -1 -1]]]
```

How can I make the c++ fftshift output matrix exactly equal to scipy's output matrix?

I tried using `xt::roll`, `xt::transpose + xt::swap`, and manual circular shift combinations, but none of them worked.

Update:
Tried using `roll`

```
    for (std::size_t axis = 0; axis < xy_.shape().size(); ++axis){
        std::size_t dim_size = xy_.shape()[axis];
        std::size_t shift = (dim_size - 1) / 2;
        xy_ = xt::roll(xy_, shift, axis);
    }
```

However, for some reason only getting right matrix that is same as the scipy.fft.fftshift one with size = 5 or size = 125. I am not sure why?

Update 2:
As per @chris' answer I added manual shift with roll. It seems to replicate scipy's fftshift but seems to be quite slow.

```cpp
template <typename T>
void fftshift_roll(xt::xarray<T>& array)
{
    std::size_t ndims = array.dimension();
    std::vector<std::ptrdiff_t> shift_indices(ndims);

    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < ndims; ++i) {
        std::ptrdiff_t shift = static_cast<std::ptrdiff_t>(array.shape(i)) / 2;
        shift_indices[i] = shift;
    }

    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < ndims; ++i) {
        auto rolled = xt::roll(array, shift_indices[i], i);
        array = xt::view(rolled, xt::all(), xt::all()); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe copy back into `array` only after the loop? Something like `xt::xarray<T> rolled = array; for() { rolled = xt::roll(rolled, ...); } array = ...;`? I haven't used xtensor before, so I don't know if `array = xt::view(rolled, xt::all(), xt::all())` is the best way to copy data over, but it seems weird syntax to me.

Comment: xtensor has some terrible documentation... not much seems to be explained.

Answer (score 1):

xtensor `fftshift` has a comment in [the source code](https://github.com/xtensor-stack/xtensor-fftw/blob/master/include/xtensor-fftw/helper.hpp):

> partly mimic np.fftshift (only 1D arrays)

So, it won’t work for your 2D case.

`roll` should do the trick. I can’t find any useful documentation for xtensor, but the function declaration for this one gives good hints:

> auto roll(E&& e, std::ptrdiff_t shift, std::ptrdiff_t axis);

So you need to apply `roll` your each axis in turn. I don’t know I’m which direction the shift happens, you’ll need to experiment a bit. The shift distance should be `size / 2`, in one direction for `fftshift`, in the other direction for `ifftshift`.

---

Do note that `fftshift` shifts the origin from the top-left corner to the middle, and `ifftshift` shifts it from the middle to the corner. For even-sized arrays this is exactly the same thing, but for odd-sized ones like the one in OP it is not.

OP has an array with the origin in a non-standard spot (not the middle, not the corner), and applying `fftshift` just happens to shift it to the corner. But this is not the normal way of using this function.

To define a coordinate system with the origin in the middle (for both even and odd-sized arrays) do

```py
np.mgrid[:size, :size] - size // 2
```

Now applying `ifftshift` will shift the origin to the corner, and applying `fftshift` on this result will move the origin back to where it was before.

Comment: thanks for the answer. Alright. I already tried roll (please see the edited question above) but that doesn't work. Could you suggest what exactly I could play around with while experimenting with `roll`? 

I didn't get the second part. You mean that I don't need to use fftshift at all? You last code snippet is already there `np.mgrid[:size, :size] - int( (size + 1)/2 )`

Comment: @Jarwin I've edited the answer to include the right distance to shift. I didn't understand your sentence "only getting right that corrosponds to scipy one with size = 5 or size = 125." ---- The second part is just to point out that the way you define your coordinate system is not standard, and does not match what `fftshift`/`ifftshift` do. `(size + 1)/2` is not the center of the array according to these functions, it's must be `size/2` (integer division).

Comment: updated the question. I meant the right matrix. And right size/2 I get that now. I'll try the roll directions as with your answer. But it seems slower than scipy already. On a different note, are you aware of any other lib that performs fftshift similar to scipy?

Comment: @Jarwin I implemented the (`i`)`fftshift` operation in C++ following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19752002/7328782), which makes it a very efficient in-place operation. They're the `ShiftCornerToCenter()` and `ShiftCenterToCorner()` functions at the top of [this file](https://github.com/DIPlib/diplib/blob/master/src/transform/fourier.cpp). Of course you can use the DIPlib library directly, it's `dip::FourierTransform()` has an option for whether the origin must be in the middle or in the corner, so there's no need to separately call a shift function.

Comment: ah alright. I'll have to look into it. dip also seems quite straightforward to use. However, since I am using the fftshift for GRF for a FEM library - it would be prudent to use something lightweight / headeronly ":D

Comment: I updated my question with an attempt. Could you please suggest again how I could implement `ShiftCornerToCenter()` in that?

Comment: @Jarwin That function runs on a single row or column of data. You'd have to loop over all rows, then over all columns. I don't know enough about the xtensor internals to quickly show you how to do this, sorry.